# show one div and hide the other div's using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show/hide div's using image map and jquery.

I need to show one div when an image map is clicked and hide the rest of the divs and hide the current div if another image map is clicked to display another div and so on and so forth!!

I have the following code which will only display the div once the image map is clicked but it doesn't hide it or `(display:none;)` if another image map is clicked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $("#vid_1").hide();
    $("#vid_2").hide();

    $("map#Map").click(function(ev){
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var targetId = target.attr('id');
    if(targetId == 'vid_One') {
      $("#vid_1").show();
    }
    });



    $("map#Map").click(function(ev){
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var targetId = target.attr('id');
    if(targetId == 'vid_Tow') {
      $("#vid_2").show();
    }
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

I don't want to use  `$("#vid_2").show();` or  `$("#vid_1").show();` etc etc  after each image map is clicked as i will have so many image maps and that will make it complicated!

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<div align="center" id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="remote">
      <img src="images/remote.png" alt="remote" width="400"
      height="681" usemap="#Map" border="0" /> <map name="Map"
      id="Map">
        <area item="menu_apps" id="vid_One" shape="circle"
        coords="68,139,32" href="#" />
        <area item="menu_apps" id="vid_Tow" shape="circle"
        coords="159,141,32" href="#" />
      </map>
    </div>
    <div id="videoContainer">
      <div id="vid_1">
        1
      </div>
      <div id="vid_2">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use css class for show and hide and add show class for one div at a time.

Comment: any chance you could explain it further? I don't see how changing ID to Class would make any difference!

Comment: show us how the <map part is looking. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

HTML Part:

```
 <map name="Map"
  id="Map">
    <area data-goto="vid_1" item="menu_apps" id="vid_One" shape="circle"
    coords="68,139,32" href="#" />
    <area data-goto="vid_2" item="menu_apps" id="vid_Tow" shape="circle"
    coords="159,141,32" href="#" />
  </map>
```

JS:

```
$("#Map area").click(function(){
  $("#videoContainer div").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data("goto")).show();
});
```

the code should hide all div elements in #videoContainer. And then show the div with the id using the data-goto value in the area element

Comment: I've added the map part as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have been facing this issue for you just show one div but did not hide other div.

Use css class say  `.show` and `.hide`. You need to use show class for one div which will display and hide class for other div those will be hide. and you need to make sure that only one div has show class at a time.

try like this:

```
 $("map#Map").click(function(ev){
        var target = $(ev.target);
        var targetId = target.attr('id');
        if(targetId == 'vid_One') {
          $(".show").removeClass("show").addClass('hide'); // remove previous div show class and hide it
          $("#vid_1").removeClass('hide').addClass("show");// remove previous div hide class and show it
        }
        });
```

let me know  if you have any confusion :)

Comment: I did try your code and it simply doesn't show any div at all! what is the HTML part of your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all your code with:

```
$("#videoContainer div").hide();

$("map#Map").click(function(ev){
    var target = $(ev.target),
        areaIndex = target.index('area');

    $("#videoContainer div:eq(" +  areaIndex + ")").hide().siblings().show();
});
```